# Samba asking for password when it shouldn't

Tags: linux, samba, arch-linux, smb

I just updated Samba on my Arch Linux machine to 4.0.5 and now it is asking for password even when it shouldn't, and didn't do before the update.

This is my smb.conf: https://gist.github.com/eaxexe/07db0488b1d04e556e61

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `security = share` mode was deprecated since Samba 3.6, and has been removed from Samba code in February 2012 ([commit d7bb961859a350](https://git.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=commit;h=d7bb961859a3501aec4d28842bfffb6190d19a73)):

```
s3-auth: Remove security=share (depricated since 3.6).

This patch removes security=share, which Samba implemented by matching
the per-share password provided by the client in the Tree Connect with
a selection of usernames supplied by the client, the smb.conf or
guessed from the environment.

The rationale for the removal is that for the bulk of security=share
users, we just we need a very simple way to run a 'trust the network'
Samba server, where users mark shares as guest ok.  This is still
supported, and the smb.conf options are documented at
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Public_Samba_Server

At the same time, this closes the door on one of the most arcane areas
of Samba authentication.
```

Comment: Thanks :) But outcomment the entire line doesn't fix the issue :(

Comment: It's not going to. You need to configure Samba to accept guest connections in `user` mode.

Comment: I must admit that I honestly don't know where to do that. Can you point me towards where I do that? Thanks!

Comment: See the "[Public Samba Server](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Public_Samba_Server)" link that's in the commit message.